# Implementing mutex in a user level thread library

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am developing a user level thread library as part of a project. I came up with an approach to implement mutex. I would like to see ur views before going on with it. Basically, i need to implement just 3 functions in my library

mutex_init, mutex_lock and mutex_unlock

I thought my mutex_t structure would look something like

```
 typedef struct 
 {
   int available; //indicates whether the mutex is locked or unlocked
   queue listofwaitingthreads;
   gtthread_t owningthread; 
 }mutex_t;
```

In my mutex_lock function, i will first check if the mutex is available in a while loop. If it is not, i will yield the processor for the next thread to execute.

In my mutex_unlock function, i will check if the owner thread is the current thread. If it is, i will set available to 0.

Is this the way to go about it ? Also, what about deadlock? Should i take care of those conditions in my user level library or should i leave the application programmers to write code properly ?

Comment: Yielding is a no op if there are no other threads ready to run so what you would have is a busy loop. Are you targetting a platform without a mutex?

Comment: Wouldn't you need another mutex to lock the listofwaitingthreads while it is being manipulated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't work, because you have a race condition. If 2 threads try to catch the lock at the same time, both will see `available == 0`, and both will think they succeeded with taking the mutex.

If you want to do this properly, and without using an already-existing lock, You must access hardware operations like TAS, CAS, etc.

There are algorithms that give you mutual exclusion without such hardware support, but they make some assumptions that are many times false. For more details about this, I highly recommend reading Herlihy and Shavit's *The art of multiprocessor programming*, chapter 7.

You shouldn't worry about deadlocks in this level - mutex locks should be simple enough, and there is some assumption that the programmer using them should use care not to cause deadlocks (advanced mutexes can check for self-deadlock, meaning a thread that calls lock twice without calling unlock in the middle).

Comment: "and both will think they succeeded with taking the mutex."   Can't they simply check owningthread to see if they're the one who actually got the lock?

Comment: @LVB in what order do you suggest to set owningthread, set available, and check owningthread?

Comment: Nevermind... I'm starting to recall a bit more about these problems and see now why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not only that you have to do atomic operations to read and modify the flag (as Eran pointed out) you also have to watch that your queue is capable to have concurrent accesses. This is not completely trivial, sort of hen and egg problem.

But if you'd really implement this by spinning, you wouldn't even need to have such a queue. The access order to the lock then would be mainly random, though.

Probably just yielding would also not be enough, this can be quite costly if you have threads holding the lock for more than some processor cycles. Consider using `nanosleep` with a low time value for the wait.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a mutex implementation should look like:

Lock:

```
while (trylock()==failed) {
    atomic_inc(waiter_cnt);
    atomic_sleep_if_locked();
    atomic_dec(waiter_cnt);
}
```

Trylock:

```
return atomic_swap(&lock, 1);
```

Unlock:

```
atomic_store(&lock, 0);
if (waiter_cnt) wakeup_sleepers();
```

Things get more complex if you want recursive mutexes, mutexes that can synchronize their own destruction (i.e. freeing the mutex is safe as soon as you get the lock), etc.

Note that `atomic_sleep_if_locked` and `wakeup_sleepers` correspond to `FUTEX_WAIT` and `FUTEX_WAKE` ops on Linux. The other atomics are probably CPU instructions, but could be system calls or kernel-assisted userspace function code, as in the case of Linux/ARM and the 0xffff0fc0 atomic compare-and-swap call.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need atomic instructions for a user level thread library, because all the threads are going to be user level threads of the same process. So actually when your process is given the time slice to execute, you are running multiple threads during that time slice but on the same processor. So, no two threads are going to be in the library function at the same time. Considering that the functions for mutex are already in the library, mutual exclusion is guaranteed.